# in node.js / socket.io - which sockets, if any, are in a "room"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

in `socket.io`, if I have a room `abc`, it there a way of knowing if anyone is in the room, for example, getting an array of sockets that have `joined` a room?

for example, in fantasy football.  admin input changes the `Payton Manning` record in the database.  a table trigger sees the change his status, so `Postgres` sends a notification to the `node.js` app.  on being notified at the app level, we wish to display Manning's stats to anyone who has drafted Manning and is online, that is, in the `Peyton Manning` room.

if no one is in the room, do not wish to do the database query, since it's pretty expensive.  otherwise will do query the db and send the stats to everyone in the room.

Answer (score 1):

Thats what im doing in my chat app

```
var sockets = io.sockets.clients(channel); /*channel = room*/
```